# facebook user cannot find my facebook app

Tags: facebook

I am new to facebook app development and i have published my app called Spydus Service but facebook user are not able to search it. It only appears in search result when user had already added the app earlier.

Is there anything that I am missing here? Is there any other way of searching/adding the apps?

Answer (score 1):

You should submit your app for approval, check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/opengraph-approval/)

Hope this helps